# show Arabic content using iText 7 Core while creating pdf in android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, pdf, itext, arabic, writer

I am working on an Project in which i have to show some Arabic Content with the english.
i'm using iText 7 core

implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.13'

with the above gradle. but it does not work as requirement.

Comment: for advanced typography features in iText7, you require [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfCalligraph).

Comment: share your sample code and pdf output you are getting

Comment: I have solved my queries. I was using pop-ins font-family for my app and iText does not support for the same so i just changed the font-family and iText working fine as per required.

Comment: I have solved my problem but it changes the text from the text i passed to it. What should i do to resolve this issue.